# Parsing structured text input and composing structured output of nested classes

Tags: c#, format, text-files, tostring

Here is my code for reading from text file. It "works" and reads from the text file but there is a small bug. It returns this: `{Employee: Name: Name: red     ID: 123     ID:     Request: Name: Name: toilet     ID: 444     Desc: water     ID:     Desc: }` I know why its doing it, I just cant figure out how to fix it. `columns[0]` value  is "Name: red \t ID: 123" and `columnms[1]` value is "Name: toilet \t ID: 444 \t Desc: water".

I know it's doing it because I'm calling  `assignment.Employee.Name` but I don't know how else to call it to get it to show on my form. I thought it would be something like `assignment.Employee` but then it gives the error that I can't convert string to the Employee type.

Assignment is a list that holds 2 objects from other lists (employee and service request).

```
public static List<Assignment> GetAssignment()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);


        StreamReader textIn =
            new StreamReader(
                new FileStream(path3, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

        List<Assignment> assignments = new List<Assignment>();

        while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string row = textIn.ReadLine();
            string[] columns = row.Split('|');
            if (columns.Length >= 2)
            {
                Assignment assignment = new Assignment();

                assignment.Employee.Name = columns[0];
                assignment.Request.Name = columns[1];
                assignments.Add(assignment);
            }
        }

        textIn.Close();

        return assignments;
    }
```

EDIT: I expect it to just return `{Employee: Name: red   ID: 123     Request:  Name: toilet      ID: 444     Desc: water}`

Comment: _"I know it's doing it because I'm calling  assignment.Employee.Name"_ I neither understand the issue nor what's causing it.

Comment: I guess we'd also need a look at your nice Employee class and at the data file ;-). But the usual general idea is to define ToString() methods for all types, bottom up, combining the ones from the lower level in an adequate fashion when converting higher levels to strings. In fact, that's what you seem to be trying to do (Assignment.ToString()  uses Employee, but probably should call Employee.ToString()).

Comment: You still haven't shown the text file, but if you say "columns[0] value is "Name: red \t ID: 123"" I assume that the word "Name" actually appears **in the text file**. That means the text file basically is a dictionary with tags ("Name", "ID" and values ("red", "123"). If that is so by format definition of the data  you must do more elaborate parsing and eliminate the "Name" portion from the column value. If that's not always so, and the meaning of a line's strings is csv format with tabs as separator chars, then you have funny data and there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't an answer but due to the strange rules on this site I am not allowed to add a comment. Please give us the definition of the class or structure called "Assignment" and tell us what you expect it to contain after your code has run.

Comment: I edited my  code with the assignment class and what i expect it to return

Comment: Yes, Aaron has spotted it :-)

Comment: @Alex: What are you doing? Editing the file while the program is running? Are you sure the file is fully written back before you call GetAssignment() again? Really for something like this the best thing to do is to step through the code with the debugger and look at local variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a `string.Format()` on the `this.Employee` so basically it is performing the default `ToString()` on the `Employee` object, which will list all fields and their associated values.  You perhaps are meaning to call it like this:

```
return string.Format("Employee: {0} \t Request: {1}", this.Employee.Name, this.Request.Name);
```

Or perhaps you want to override the `ToString()` on your `Employee` and `ServiceRequest` objects to return your desired results.

Update

Since you edited your question to include the `Employee` object, the above is not relevant.  Since your `column[0]` value actually has the text `"Name: red \t ID: 123"` then in your `Employee` override of `ToString` you do not also need to specify the text `"Name:"`.

Comment: That fixes the problem of reading from the text file (it gives me my expected output). But now when i add an assignment when im running the program it doesn't work. So when i add an assignment, instead of it showing all fields for employee/service request it only shows the name

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that a typical text line in your data file looks like this:

> Name: red \t ID: 123 | Name: toilet \t ID: 444 \t Desc: water

This looks to me like it is encoding two objects, the first one having two attributes (Name and ID) and the second one having three attributes (Name, ID, Desc).

Objects within the same line are separated by pipe signs ("|"). Attributes within the same object are separated by tabs ("\t"). Each attribute consists of an identifier ("Name", "ID") and a value ("red", "123"), separated by a colon (":"). The natural data structure for such pairs would be a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Reading such a file would emulate that nesting.

- Read a line; split it by "|" into strings containing one object each (your columns).
- Split each of these object strings by \t so that each resulting string contains one key and one value with a colon (":") and white space between them.
- Split each of those key-values by ":" to separate the key from the value. Trim both to get rid of excess white space.

Employees or other objects of this kind hold a dictionary to store the key/value pairs, and ToString() just prints each pair by printing a key, a colon, and the value.

Comment: That's what it looks like in the text file, but the \t doesnt show in the text file. There's just a white space instead

Comment: Well, "\t" is how the particular white space with the ASCII code 9, the TAB character, is printed if one wants to distinguish it from the other whitespace with the ASCII code 32. ;-) If in doubt look at it in a hex editor, or look at the specification for the file (there is one, isn't there?). In program source code "\t" is frequently used to specify a (single) TAB at that position in a string.